# How to print all the data in datagrid view in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, button, printing, datagridview

I have a form that retrieves all the data in MS Excel once the button is clicked.

And what I want to do is, when the datagrid successfully retrieved all the data, I have a button that preview the data that will be be print in pages which is I think is the setup before you print it.

I do not have any idea how to do that.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PrintDialog Control to be able to choose the printer and section of your form you want to print.

Take a look at this link.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_print_dialog.htm